# reStructuredText: Automatic table of contents for standalone .rst file

Tags: pandoc, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm a Markdown user but recently I came across reStructuredText and I wanted to take advantage of its features to create technical documents in pdf.

I know this markup language is mainly used with Sphinx to create Python package documentation, but I wanted to know if I can also use it outside of Python to create simple pdf documents, just like I would with Markdown via Pandoc.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm using only one .rst file like this which I render to pdf

```
=====
Title
=====


.. contents::


some text...

Chapter 1
---------

some text...

Chapter 2
---------

some text...
```

What I would like to do is create a table of contents for this single .rst file, to be converted into PDF, which contains the references of the sections of this page (i.e. the chapters and any sub-chapters and paragraphs). Since I don't have any other external file `.. toctree::` doesn't help me and even using `.. contents::` I didn't get the desired result (actually I didn't get any table of contents in my final pdf output).

With Markdown this was easy to achieve by using `toc: true` in the preamble like in this example

```
---
title: "Title"
toc: true
---

some text...

# Chapter 1


some text...

# Chapter 2

some text...


... and so on
```

Trying to be clear, this is my project folder structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── test.rst
└── test.pdf
```

Through the Makefile I convert my .rst file to pdf. This is the source code of my Makefile faithfully inspired by [lmullen's idea](https://gist.github.com/lmullen/3767386) in which it converts a .md file into .pdf.

The content of my Makefile is as follows:

```
PDFS := $(patsubst %.rst,%.pdf,$(wildcard *.rst))


all : $(PDFS)

              
%.pdf : %.rst
    pandoc $< -o $@


clean:
    rm $(PDFS)

rebuild : clean all
```

There's probably a lot to fix here to make it more flexible, but that's what I've managed to do so far.

I am therefore able to leverage the rst markup language to create a pdf content but having no experience with reStructuredText I am unable to create a table of contents for the sections of this .rst file, as I would be able to do using markdown.

I hope the request was clear and that some of you can help me.

Comment: Do you use Sphinx? Or Pandoc? Which tool do you intend to use to generate the PDF?

Comment: I was planning to convert it with Pandoc via a Makefile. So without using Sphinx, although I'd be glad to know if something like this can be achieved easily with Sphinx as well.

Comment: I've edited my post above to describe my current workflow. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Your question does not show how you use the `contents` directive. This should work, if not, then maybe it is a *Pandoc* bug. If you have a GitHub account, you could create a ***gist*** with a minimal `.rst` document showing the issue.

Comment: I did create a ***gist***, and for me there was no issue, GitHub was able to render a table of contents with the `contents` directive.

Comment: I edited the post again inserting the `.. contents::`, maybe I wrote it wrong, I don't know. Or as you say it's a pandoc bug. In fact, I forgot to mention that when I execute the `make` command on the terminal, I get warnings:

`pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.`

Where can I see the results of your `gist`?

Comment: Seems like it's a *pandoc* limitation: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4108 -- I recommend you rewrite your question and make it clear that you are working with pandoc, because as it is now, your question has a lot of text but still does not say clearly that you are working with pandoc, it is only when reading the Makefile that one can know that. Really we do not need the Markdown or the Makefile (we need the pandoc command though). Also if you do not use Sphinx then no need to mention it. Really I recommend you keep your question simple and straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that *Pandoc* intentionally ignores the `.. contents::` directive in reStructuredText files: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4108

Here is a [link to an online *Pandoc* editor](https://pandoc.org/try/?params=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Title%5Cn%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%5Cn%5Cn..+contents%3A%3A%5Cn%5CnOne%5Cn---%5Cn%5CnText.%5Cn%5CnTwo%5Cn---%5Cn%5CnText.%5Cn%22%2C%22to%22%3A%22html5%22%2C%22from%22%3A%22rst%22%2C%22standalone%22%3Afalse%2C%22embed-resources%22%3Afalse%2C%22table-of-contents%22%3Afalse%2C%22number-sections%22%3Afalse%2C%22citeproc%22%3Afalse%2C%22html-math-method%22%3A%22plain%22%2C%22wrap%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22highlight-style%22%3Anull%2C%22files%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3Anull%7D) showing that no table of contents is written in the output.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Pandoc, you might want to try **rst2pdf**. It supports the `contents` directive.

Take a look at the "Structured Document" example here: https://rst2pdf.org/examples.

Comment: rst2pdf also provides a PDF extension for Sphinx: https://rst2pdf.org/static/manual.html#sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

The [Docutils](https://docutils.sourceforce.io) Python package converts a single reStructuredText file into a variety of output formats.
It also supports all features of standard [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) including the `.. contents::` directive.

So, unless you object to anything based on Python, it seems to be a tool matching the task without the overhead of Sphinx.
Save your example to`test.rst`, say and run  `rst2latex test.rst > test.tex` followed by `pdflatex test.tex`.

Alternatively use the already mentioned `rst2pdf` converter that uses Docutils and ReportLab (instead of LaTeX).